# Where does this relationship between the Dirac and vector representations of the Lorentz group come from?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

We have been asked to show that there is a relation between the $(1/2,0)\oplus(0,1/2)$ (Dirac rep $R_D$) and the $(1/2,1/2)$ (vector rep $R_V$) representations of the Lorentz group:

$$
R_D(M)\gamma_\mu R_D(M)^{-1}=R_V(M)^\nu_\mu \gamma _\nu
,$$
where $M$ is just some element in the Lorentz group.

The only hint we are given is that the Lie algebras of the Lorentz group and $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ are isomorphic.

Comment: The proof that physicists use shows that $R_V (\Lambda) = \Lambda$ and follows from the Lorentz invariance of the Dirac equation.